# Make fibonacci in tuple

Tags: python

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return (0,)
    count = 1
    while n > count:
        a , b = 0, 1
        c = a +b
        a,b = b,c
        count += 1
        return (b,c)
    return (0,) + (b,c)
```

This is my code and I can't get the desired output.

```
make_fibonacci(5)

(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is this the desired or the actual output?

Comment: This is the desired output, the actual output is `(1, 1)`

Comment: You wanted to write a _recursive_ implementation, but ended up writing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this one

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return (0,)
    count = 1
    x = [0]
    a, b = 0, 1
    while n >= count:
        count += 1
        a, b = b, a+b
        x += [a]

    return tuple(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print make_fibonacci(5)
```

output is:

```
(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `return` in the `while` loop, so of course it'll never iterate.

It looks as if you were thinking of doing something recursive, but you failed to actually *do* the recursive part, i.e. call `make_fibonacci()` from inside itself.

I would recommend dropping the tuple idea and instead focus on building a plain old list of the numbers, then convert to tuple when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code that doesn't require `recursion`:

```
def make_fibonacci(n):
    result = [0,1]
    if n < 1:
        return [0]
    count = 1
    while count < n:
        count += 1
        result.append(result[-1]+result[-2])
    return result

>>> print make_fibonacci(5)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: He didn't ask for that, I'm sure there are many solutions to be found on google too but they're not really relevant here